# "have been adopted to" vs "have been adopted for"

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure whether I should use "to" or "for" here:

> Machine learning methods have been widely adopted to classify images?

Or

> Machine learning methods have been widely adopted for classifying images?

Which sentence sounds better?

Comment: Have you checked whether "have been adopted to + V" and "have been adopted for + [the +] N or ing-form" are widely used on the internet? There seem to be large numbers of examples of both. I'd probably use 'Machine learning methods have been widely adopted for the classifying of images', being as l as I am.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as posed, it is a request for an opinion about "which wording sounds better." If it were reframed as a question about whether one form is more widely used than the other or whether both forms are common in spoken and written English, I think it would be legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the examples found in the following [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adopted+to+classify%2Cadopted+for+classifying&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadopted%20to%20classify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadopted%20for%20classifying%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cadopted%20to%20classify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadopted%20for%20classifying%3B%2Cc0), both are in use; the frequency of the use of "for" was greater in the past and the overall number of occurrences of it is greater.

[image]

Weighing in the balance in the aim of showing that "for" is much preferred by native speakers (of some sort, English, American, …), is the fact that the use of "to" appears to be associated importantly enough with writers from Asia or from Asian origin, and possibly other foreign users of the language.

This can be checked on the pages of examples: "[adopted to classify](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adopted%20to%20classify%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)", "[adopted for classifying](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adopted%20for%20classifying%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)".

This tends to show that "for" is found to express purpose with a greater definiteness.
To reinforce this contention there is the fact that in the OALD, "for" is found to be defined specifically as showing purpose, whereas "to" is not; this is however not the case for all references since purpose is mentioned in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to) and in [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/to).

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/for_1?q=for)) **for** used to show purpose or function
> ♦ a machine for slicing bread
> ♦ Let's go for a walk.
> ♦ Are you learning English for pleasure or for your work?
> ♦ What did you do that for (= Why did you do that)?

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/to_1?q=to)) **to**

Also, the infinitive clause (use of "to") shows a complex pattern of usage.

> (*Practical English Usage*, 2nd edition 1996)
> We often use an infinitive to talk about a person's purpose —why he or she does something.
> ♦ *I sat down **to rest***
> ♦ *He went abroad **to forget***.
> ♦ ***To switch on**, press red button*.
> *In order to* and *so as to* are normal before 'stative' verbs like *be*, *know*, and *have*.
> ♦ I watched him in order to know more abour t him.
> (More natural than than *I watched him **to know** more about him*.)
> We normally use *in order / so as* before a negative infinitive.
> ♦ *I'm going to leave now **so as not to be** late*.
> (NOT <s>*I'm going to leave now **not to be** late*.</s>

All of that tends to show that denoting purpose by means of "to" is a relatively uneasy process of unsure result and that the use of  "for" is preferred because it seems straightforward enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your questions lies specifically in the difference in usage of 'to' and 'for'. To my knowledge, 'to' is used when you are receiving or giving something directly. 'For' is used when you are talking about usage ( which you are here ), so I would recommend you use 'for'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the latter one using *for* sounds better.

As there seems no phrases like *adopt sth. to do sth.* or *adopt sth. for doing sth.* exist, both sentences seems fine.

Though I think this is beyond the tagged *preposition* range. As the *to* in the first sentence is forming an infinitive rather than working as a prep. if it is used this way.

Both *to*-infinitive and *for* work as complements for *adopt*. [Infinitive can express purpose, intent, result and more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Uses_of_the_infinitive), and here the infinitive could be expressing the intent just the same as *for*; so both sentences are nearly the same regarding this.